SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG при проксировании nextcloud (http -> https) через Nginx Proxy Manager
Nginx Proxy Manager поднят контейнером в Docker и nextcloud тоже. Оба контейнера находятся в одной сети "proxy" и друг друга видят, т.к. если не применять SSL, то проксирование проходит идеально и nextcloud без проблем открывается в браузере. В логах никаких ошибок нет.
docker-compose.yml для Nextcloud
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nextcloud
      MYSQL_USER: nextcloud
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: nextcloud
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=nextcloud
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - CRON_PERIOD=5m
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - proxy

  cron:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud-cron
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

